# Sidekiq not adding jobs to queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Sometime ago I wrote a small Ruby application which uses Sidekiq to convert video files and pushes them further to few online video hosting services. I use two Workers and Queues, one to actually convert file and second to publish converted files. Jobs are pushed to first Queue by Rails application for conversion, and after successful processing Conversion Worker pushes Upload job to second queue.

```
 Rails -> Converter Queue -> Uploader Queue
```

Recently I discover a massive memory leak in converter library which appears after every few jobs and overloads whole server, so I did a little hack to avoid this by stopping whole Sidekiq Worker process using `Interrupt` exception and starting it again by Systemd.

It works perfectly until yesterday. I get notification from my client that files are not converted. I did some investigation to find out whats failing and found that jobs are not added to Converter queue. It starts failing without any changes in code or services. When Rails adds jobs to Sidekiq Queue it receives proper Job ID, no exception or warning at all, but the job simply not appears in any Queue. I checked Redis logs, Systemd logs, dmesg, every logs that i could check and did not find even the slightest warning - it seems that jobs get lost in vacuum :/ In fact, after more digging and debugging I discover that if one job is pushed rapidly ( 100 times in a loop ), then there is a chance that Sidekiq will add job to Queue. Of course, sometimes it will add all jobs, and sometimes not even single one.

The second Queue works perfectly - it picks every single job that I add to it. When I try to add 1000 new jobs, second Queue queues them all, when Converter queue gets at best 10 jobs. Things gets really weird when I try to use another Queue - I pushed 100 jobs to a new Queue, of course all of them are added properly and then I instruct Conversion worker to use that new Queue. And it works - I can add new Jobs to that Queue and it seems that all of them are pushed successfully - but when Worker finish processing all jobs that were pushed before that Worker was assigned to this Queue it starts to failing again. Disabling code that restarts Worker after every job didn't help at all.

Funny thing is that in fact jobs are pushed to Queue but only when I pushes them multiple times, and it seems totally random when Job is added properly. This bugs appears from nowhere, for few months things works perfectly and recently starts failing without any changes in code or server. Logs are perfectly clear, Sidekiq is used with the same Redis server without any problems by few other applications - it seems that only this particular Worker have this problem. I did not found any references to similar bug on the web and I spent two days trying to debug this and find source of this weird behavior, and I found nothing, everything seems to work perfectly and Jobs are simply disappearing somewhere between push and Redis database.

Comment: Without seeing the code, this is very hard to answer. Can you post the code you're using to enqueue the jobs that are disappearing?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that is the source of problem. In Rails app I push jobs to Queue using `Converter.perform_async movie.id`, where movie is a AR object which is already saved in DB. This same bug also appears when I try to queue jobs using lower level API - `Sidekiq::Client.push 'class' => Converter, 'args' => [movie.id]`. I forgot to mention that when I enqueue job passing different value as class to this API, for example a string (`'class' => 'TestClass'`) it's get queued every time, so there is something definitely wrong with Worker Class.

Comment: Source code of the Converter Worker: http://pastebin.com/HnSN5WRJ . I had to remove all processing code due to my customer agreement, but it is only a few lines of code and I don't think that is source of this problem because it still failing even when I remove it and leave only these code which I published.

Comment: And Sidekiq configuration file: http://pastebin.com/sjAaKcgA

Comment: Does the issue still happen if you remove the interrupt code? That seems like it might cause some funky behavior.

Comment: Actually yes and no. If I start a new Queue and remove interruption it seems that Queue is working perfectly. But, with the same Queue, if I add this exception it's starts behave exactly like before, even when I remove this code again (without changing Queue). It's like that a broken Worker can somehow affect whole Queue. I try to find another solution for these memory leaks, it will be hard :/ Thanks.